# Can you pattern match a non empty array in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a `User` model with a `has_many` relationship to `other_model`.
I have a function `Search` that searches the internet. What I would like to do is search the internet only if the `has_many` relationship is not an empty array.

So I'm wondering if I can pattern match against a non-empty array? As you can see below, the extra `Search` results in nested branch and hence I use the `with` statement and am hoping for a clean solution.

```
query = from a in Model, where: a.id == ^id, preload: [:some_associations]

with %{some_associations: some_associations} <- Repo.one(query),
      {:ok, some_results} <- Search.call(keywords, 1) do
            do_something_with(some_associations, some_results)
else
    nil -> IO.puts "query found nothing"
    {:error, reason} -> IO.puts "Search or query returned error with reason #{reason}"
end
```

Comment: You mean like `{:ok, some_results = [_ | _]} <- ...`?

Comment: I need some_associatuons to be not empty. hmmm I'll try that when I get home. Didn't realise you can do that...

Comment: @Dogbert you need to post some of those as answers :)  People will miss them in the comments. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the pattern `[_ | _]` to match non-empty lists:

```
{:ok, some_results = [_ | _]} <- Search.call(keywords, 1)
```

```
iex(1)> with xs = [_|_] <- [1, 2, 3] do {:ok, xs} else _ -> :error end
{:ok, [1, 2, 3]}
iex(2)> with xs = [_|_] <- [] do {:ok, xs} else _ -> :error end
:error
```

Comment: Is there a way to pattern match a non empty list containing a specific type of structs? Like `[%User{}, %User{}, %User{}, %User{} ...]` ?

Comment: Yes. `[%User{} | _]`.